# Vocabulary List From word2vec and GloVe

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embeddings

Is there a way I can access just the vocabulary list of pre-trained vectors for word2vec and GloVe? I do not need the entire n-dimensional embeddings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: Yes, you can.

You need to first load the vectors using the Gensim module in Python.

```py
# Load Google news vectors
word2vec_path = "path_to_the_vectors/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin"
word2vec = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(word2vec_path, binary=True)

# contains the list of all unique words in pre-trained word2vec vectors
w2v_vocabulary = word2vec.vocab
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be done by pre-processing the word embedding file in the following way :

```
with open('glove.txt') as f:
    text = f.readlines()

word_list = [line.strip().split()[0] for line in text]
```